# Find rectangle boundries with any angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, algebra

I have a rectangle that has an angle and i need to find its boundaries in an equality form ( less than, greater than).

so i guess the best way to start is to tell you what i know

CENTER: (rect_width/2, rect_height/2)

ANGLE: 225 degrees (anything besides 0,90,180,270,360,etc.)

The rectangle's angle is not fixed to the position coordinate system, think  of it as if the rectangle has its own coordinate system

So in other words there are 2 coordinate systems one for the placement of the rectangle and the other that stays fixed to the origin of the rectangle's CENTER which helps determine the angle.

Sorry for my horrible photo editing
[Visual rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YEig.png)

Comment: Something like `RegionBounds@TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[phi]]` will work.